# JPG в строку Base64 и обратно (Python)

Tags: python, json, base64, jpeg

У меня 2 изображения формата **JPG**, я хочу передать их в свой **API** как файл **JSON**, зашифровав в **Base64** как строку, потом на сервере я получаю этот файл и превращаю обратно в изображение. Я искал способы как **JPG** зашифровать в строку **Base64**, но то ли я что-то сделал не так, то ли тот код не верный (Изображения не открываются, пишет что они повреждены).

---

Вот код кодирования изображения **(Python)**:

```
import base64
import json

inp1 = input("Enter file1 name: ")
inp2 = input("Enter file2 name: ")

with open(inp1, "rb") as image_file:
    str1 = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

with open(inp2, "rb") as image_file:
    str2 = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())  

with open("test.json", 'w') as f:
    data = {"style":str(str1), "image":str(str2)}
    json.dump(data, f)
```

В двух input'ах пишем имена файлов: *style.jpg и image.jpg*

---

Результатом должен стать **JSON** файл, он будет выглядить так:

```
{"style":"<Строка Base64>", "image":"<Строка Base64>"}
```

---

Потом мы загрузили наш **JSON** файл на сервер и там уже мы дешифруем наши строки:

```
def base64_to_image(img):
    data = base64.b64decode(img)
    name = f'uploads/img{random.randint(0, 10000)}.jpg'
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
    return name

with open('uploads/test.json') as json_file:
# JSON файл хранится в папке uploads
    data = json.load(json_file)
    style = data['style']
    image = data['image']

    base64_to_image(style)
    base64_to_image(image)
```

---

*В итоге мы получаем два не рабочих изображения в папке uploads, как это исправить?*

Comment: `str(str1)` делает скорее всего не то что вы думаете, попробуйте `str1.decode('ascii')`

Comment: Почему `шифрации` если правильно будет сказать `кодировать`

Comment: @andreymal, Не помогло, как не работало, так и не работает

Comment: А если на одной машине закинуть в json изображения и сразу достать их, а после преобразовать назад в изображения? Вдруг они повреждаются при передаче? Или же попробовать не использовать base64 - определить, может в нем нюанс.

Comment: @merive_, не знаю что у вас не получается, но с исправлением, предложенным andreymal все работает: https://github.com/insolor/base64_images/blob/master/base64_images.ipynb

Comment: Очень странно, но на другой машине работает. Всем спасибо за помощь)